# Hard Starting only when warm - getting camshaft position sensor codes, but have replaced them

Tags: buick, hot-start, regal, camshaft-position-sensor

Have a 2012 Buick Regal Ecotec 2.4 with 95K miles.
Had engine light with PO340 code to replace camshaft position sensor.
Was getting no drive-ability issues at the time, but replaced sensors.

After a few months, now getting hard starts when engine is hot.
No issues starting when cold and no issues while driving.
When the hard starts happen (long crank before starting), it's throwing the camshaft position sensor codes.  I doubt that's it -- what are the odds that the CPS are bad again?  ...and why only when hot?

All help appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: How is the health of your timing chain/belt? When was the last time replaced or checked? If it is near the replacement limit, getting hot expands it more and therefore getting out of spec. The ECU can detect those issues because on modern cars there are multiple sensors that check and report timing.

Comment: yah, not sure, thanks, is that different than the serpentine belt?

Comment: serpentine belt is a type of belt, there at least 2 belts on a motor, but the timing belt is the one you replace every 100km in most engines and connects the camshaft/s to your crankshaft, it is one of the most important belts.